# Feign Oauth2 client token exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-feign

I m trying to get feign Client to work over my Oauth2 SSO

I have defined a bean interceptor as below

```
@Bean
        @LoadBalanced
        RequestInterceptor oauthFeignClient(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
            return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(oauth2ClientContext, details);
        }
```

but I m facing this exception :

> feign.FeignException: status 401 reading AppClientFeign#getApps(); content:
>   {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"9d8eb02c-7005-487e-b28f-19417e5fea51"}

I don't know why I m getting this

Here is my Auth server

```
 @Configuration
        static class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("login").setViewName("login");
            registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
            }
        }

        @Configuration
        static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


            @Bean
            public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
                return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            }
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                        .and().logout().clearAuthentication(true).invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/exit").logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:9999/client").permitAll()
                    .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/","/exit","/graphics/**", "/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").permitAll()
                    .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and().httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable();
            }

            @Autowired
            MDSUserDetailService mdsUserServiceDetail;
            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
               auth.userDetailsService(mdsUserServiceDetail).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            }


        }
```

and My yaml configuration

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        client-id: xxx
        client-secret: xxx
        scope: read, write
        auto-approve-scopes: .*
      authorization:
        check-token-access: permitAll()
```

here is my client

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ClientApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApplication.class, args);
    }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:9999/uaa/exit");
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("graphics/**").permitAll().
                    and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }


        @Bean
        @LoadBalanced
        RequestInterceptor oauthFeignClient(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
            return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(oauth2ClientContext, details);
        }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
    }

    @Profile("!cloud")
    @Bean
    RequestDumperFilter requestDumperFilter() {
        return new RequestDumperFilter();
    }

}
```

the Feign Client Interface

```
@FeignClient("USERS-MANAGER")
public interface UserClientFeign {
      @GetMapping("/users/info")
      public User getUserDetails(@RequestParam("username") String username);
}
```

yml configuration of my client

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: xxx
      client-secret: xxx
      access-token-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/authorize
      scope: read, write
    resource:
      token-info-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/check_token
```

finally my ressource

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
public class ResourceApplication extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {



    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Profile("!cloud")
    @Bean
    RequestDumperFilter requestDumperFilter() {
        return new RequestDumperFilter();
    }
}
```

the yml configuration

```
spring.application.name: USERS-MANAGER

server:
  port: 0

ribbon:
    eureka:
        enabled: true

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri:  http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/check_token
    client:
      client-id:  xxx
      client-secret:  xxx
```

the exception in browser

> Thu Sep 13 14:19:52 BST 2018
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   status 401 reading AppClientFeign#getApps(); content: {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"9d8eb02c-7005-487e-b28f-19417e5fea51"}

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky to find out why token is invalid without any detailed description. It could be token expired too fast( due to your token TTL set up ), or token's grant type or maybe token's scope is different that what resource server requires.

You might want to add breakpoint at several point in `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter#doFilter()`, and see what's the value you are getting from oauth2 provider, and compare it with the token value that client is using. Especially take a look call around `authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);`